# Entity Framework, SQL Server circular DB schema error for blog API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework

I am new to SQL Server database design let alone C# and the .NET framework. I was wondering if I could get some help regarding the implementation of my SQL Server database with a simple blogging API.

Here is the diagram that I drew up:

[Blog Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP6Ih.png)

Here are the model classes that I have created for this blog:

```
namespace Dotnet_blog.Models.Domain
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int Likes { get; set; }
        public int Dislikes { get; set; }

        // Reference
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        // Reference
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Dotnet_blog.Models.Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        // Reference here
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Dotnet_blog.Models.Domain
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
        public int Dislikes { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        // Reference here
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }

        // Reference here
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my `ApplicationDBContext` for creating the
SQL objects

```
using Dotnet_blog.Models.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Dotnet_blog.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options):base(options) //pass options to parent class.
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // This commented out section seems to not work.
            //builder.Entity<Comment>()
            //    .HasOne(comment => comment.User)
            //    .WithMany(user => user.Comments);

            //builder.Entity<Blog>()
            //    .HasOne(blog => blog.User)
            //    .WithMany(user => user.Blogs);

            //builder.Entity<Comment>()
            //    .HasOne(comment => comment.Blog)
            //    .WithMany(blog => blog.Comments);
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comment_User_UserId' on table 'Comment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Can anyone help me figuring out this error? That would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that I was getting had to do with the fact that I had Comments cascade deleting from the user AND the blog. If I just set the cascade delete on the blog, then the comments will delete even if the user is deleted. This ultimately fixed my problem. I appreciate all the help from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
builder.Entity("Comment", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("User", null)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("UserId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired();
    });
builder.Entity("Comment", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("Blog", null)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("BlogId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired();
    });
builder.Entity("Blog", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("User", null)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("UserId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired();
    });
```